# How can I construct a Python3 file object from a full file path (string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, email-attachments

I am updating a mailer from Python2. There I used the line

```
attachFile.set_payload(file(attachment[1]).read())
```

How can I create the same effect in Python3? I tried

```
attachFile.set_payload(File(attachment[1]).read())
```

but am told that File() is not known. file() does not work either.

attachment[1] contains the full path to the file on the Ubuntu file system.

Thank you.

Comment: You are looking for `open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
attachFile.set_payload(open(attachment[1], "rb").read())
```

which is opening file in binary mode (I assume this is what is needed here).

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work now. Yet I am stuck with having to set uo a STARTTLS context, since the mail server I intended to use has upgraded login security since my 2.7 script last run. I will have to study this in more details before the mailer is successfully migrated.

Comment: @Progg: since you found my answer useful could you please mark the question as answered (grey tick besides the answer)?